Adding x264 and AAC encoding to a Telegram-based FFmpeg script
I'm trying to modify a Telegram script that utilizes static FFmpeg and VPX libraries to also include x264 and AAC encoding. I'm quite new to this and could use some guidance.
Background:
Telegram uses static .a files of FFmpeg and VPX, compiled using NDK. I have the script that builds these libraries. I want to modify this script to include x264 and AAC libraries as well.
Problem:
I'm unsure how to integrate x264 and AAC into the existing build process and how to configure FFmpeg to use these codecs.
Code snippets:
build_ffmpeg.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# instructions for build
# used
# ffmpeg 4.4.3
# lib vpx 1.10.9
# NDK for compile libvpx. Last successful build with 21.1.6352462
# NDK r10e for compile ffmpeg
#
# 1) download ffmpeg
# 2) set NDK_r10e and NDK variables
# 3) download lib vpx
# 4) copy libvpx to vpx-android folder and rename as libvpx
# 5) copy build_ffmpeg foleder in ffmepg directory
# 6) run build_ffmpeg.sh
# 7) see compiled library in build_ffmpeg/adnroid folder

NDK="/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462"
NDK_r10e="/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10e"

#build vpx
cd ./vpx-android
export ANDROID_NDK=$NDK
sh build-vpx.sh
cd ..

cd ./x264-android
export ANDROID_NDK=$NDK
sh build.sh
cd ..

NDK=$NDK_r10e

function build_one {

echo "Cleaning..."
rm config.h
make clean

echo "Configuring..."

INCLUDES=" -I${PREFIX}/include"
LIBS=" -L${PREFIX}/lib"

cd /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/ffmpeg-4.4.3
./configure \
--cc=$CC \
--nm=$NM \
--enable-stripping \
--arch=$ARCH \
--target-os=linux \
--enable-cross-compile \
--yasmexe=$NDK/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/yasm \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-pic \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--enable-asm \
--enable-inline-asm \
--cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM \
--extra-cflags="${INCLUDES} -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Os -DCONFIG_LINUX_PERF=0 -DANDROID $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS -fPIE -pie --static -fPIC" \
--extra-ldflags="${LIBS} -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -fPIC" \
--extra-libs="-lgcc" \
\
--enable-version3 \
--enable-gpl \
\
--disable-doc \
--disable-avx \
\
--disable-everything \
--disable-network \
--disable-zlib \
--disable-avfilter \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-postproc \
--disable-debug \
--disable-programs \
--disable-network \
\
--enable-libvpx \
--enable-decoder=libvpx_vp9 \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--enable-pthreads \
--enable-avresample \
--enable-swscale \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
--enable-decoder=mjpeg \
--enable-decoder=gif \
--enable-decoder=alac \
--enable-decoder=opus \
--enable-demuxer=mov \
--enable-demuxer=gif \
--enable-demuxer=ogg \
--enable-demuxer=matroska \
--enable-hwaccels \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

#echo "continue?"
#read
make -j8 install

}

#x86_64
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64
LD=$PREBUILT/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld
AR=$PREBUILT/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar
NM=$PREBUILT/bin/x86_64-linux-android-nm
GCCLIB=$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/libgcc.a
CC=$PREBUILT/bin/x86_64-linux-android-gcc
CROSS_PREFIX=$PREBUILT/bin/x86_64-linux-android-
ARCH=x86_64
CPU=x86_64
PREFIX=./android/x86_64
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG="--disable-mmx --disable-inline-asm"
build_one

#arm64-v8a
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
LD=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld
AR=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
NM=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-nm
GCCLIB=$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/libgcc.a
CC=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc
CROSS_PREFIX=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
ARCH=arm64
CPU=arm64-v8a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS=
PREFIX=./android/arm64-v8a
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG="--enable-neon --enable-optimizations"
build_one

#arm v7n
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-16/arch-arm
LD=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
AR=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
NM=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm
GCCLIB=$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libgcc.a
CC=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
CROSS_PREFIX=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
ARCH=arm
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
PREFIX=./android/armeabi-v7a
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--enable-neon
build_one

#x86
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-16/arch-x86
LD=$PREBUILT/bin/i686-linux-android-ld
AR=$PREBUILT/bin/i686-linux-android-ar
NM=$PREBUILT/bin/i686-linux-android-nm
GCCLIB=$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9/libgcc.a
CC=$PREBUILT/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
CROSS_PREFIX=$PREBUILT/bin/i686-linux-android-
ARCH=x86
CPU=i686
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-march=$CPU"
PREFIX=./android/x86
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG="--disable-mmx --disable-yasm"
build_one

  if [[ -e ./build_ffmpeg/android ]]; then
      rm -rf ./build_ffmpeg/android
  fi

mv ./android ./build_ffmpeg/

build-vpx.sh:
#!/bin/bash

set -u
. _settings.sh

LIB_VPX="libvpx"
LIB_GIT=v1.10.0

if [[ -f "${LIB_VPX}/build/make/version.sh" ]]; then
  version=`"${LIB_VPX}/build/make/version.sh" --bare "${LIB_VPX}"`
fi

configure_make() {
  pushd "${LIB_VPX}" || exit
  ABI=$1;
  echo -e "\n** BUILD STARTED: ${LIB_VPX} (${version}) for ${ABI} **"

  configure "$@"
  case ${ABI} in
    armeabi)
      TARGET="armv7-android-gcc --disable-neon --disable-neon-asm"
    ;;
    armeabi-v7a)
      TARGET="armv7-android-gcc --enable-neon --disable-neon-asm"
    ;;
    arm64-v8a)
      TARGET="arm64-android-gcc"
    ;;
    x86)
      TARGET="x86-android-gcc"
    ;;
    x86_64)
      TARGET="x86_64-android-gcc"
    ;;
    mips)
      TARGET="mips32-linux-gcc"
    ;;
    mips64)
      TARGET="mips64-linux-gcc"
    ;;
  esac

make clean

CPU_DETECT="--disable-runtime-cpu-detect"
if [[ $1 =~ x86.* ]]; then
   CPU_DETECT="--enable-runtime-cpu-detect"
fi

  ./configure \
    --extra-cflags="-isystem ${NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/include/${NDK_ABIARCH} -isystem ${NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/include" \
    --libc=${NDK_SYSROOT} \
    --prefix=${PREFIX} \
    --target=${TARGET} \
    ${CPU_DETECT} \
    --as=auto \
    --disable-docs \
    --enable-pic \
    --enable-libyuv \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-small \
    --enable-optimizations \
    --enable-better-hw-compatibility \
    --enable-realtime-only \
    --enable-vp8 \
    --enable-vp9 \
    --disable-webm-io \
    --disable-examples \
    --disable-tools \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-unit-tests || exit 1

  make -j${HOST_NUM_CORES} install
  popd || true
}

for ((i=0; i < ${#ABIS[@]}; i++))
do
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] || [[ "$1" == "${ABIS[i]}" ]]; then
    [[ ${ANDROID_API} -lt 21 ]] && ( echo "${ABIS[i]}" | grep 64 > /dev/null ) && continue;
    configure_make "${ABIS[i]}"
    echo -e "** BUILD COMPLETED: ${LIB_VPX} for ${ABIS[i]} **\n\n"
  fi
done

_settings.sh:
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $ANDROID_NDK ]] || [[ ! -d $ANDROID_NDK ]] ; then
    echo "You need to set ANDROID_NDK environment variable, exiting"
    echo "Use: export ANDROID_NDK=/your/path/to/android-ndk-rxx"
    echo "e.g.: export ANDROID_NDK=/opt/android/android-ndk-r18b"
    exit 1
fi

set -u

ANDROID_API=21

ABIS=("armeabi-v7a" "arm64-v8a" "x86" "x86_64")

BASEDIR=`pwd`
NDK=${ANDROID_NDK}
HOST_NUM_CORES=$(nproc)

CFLAGS_="-DANDROID -fpic -fpie"
LDFLAGS_=""

configure() {
  ABI=$1;

  case $ABI in
    armeabi)
      NDK_ARCH="arm"
      NDK_ABIARCH="arm-linux-androideabi"
      CFLAGS="-march=armv5 -marm -finline-limit=64"
      LDFLAGS=""
      ASFLAGS=""
    ;;
    armeabi-v7a)
      NDK_ARCH="arm"
      NDK_ABIARCH="arm-linux-androideabi"
      CFLAGS="${CFLAGS_} -Os -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 -mthumb -D__thumb__"
      LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS_} -march=armv7-a"
      ASFLAGS=""
    ;;
    arm64-v8a)
      NDK_ARCH="arm64"
      NDK_ABIARCH="aarch64-linux-android"
      CFLAGS="${CFLAGS_} -O3 -march=armv8-a"
      LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS_}"
      ASFLAGS=""
    ;;
    x86)
      NDK_ARCH="x86"
      NDK_ABIARCH="i686-linux-android"
      CFLAGS="${CFLAGS_} -O3 -march=i686 -mtune=intel -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -m32 -fPIC"
      LDFLAGS="-m32"
      ASFLAGS="-D__ANDROID__"
    ;;
    x86_64)
      NDK_ARCH="x86_64"
      NDK_ABIARCH="x86_64-linux-android"
      CFLAGS="${CFLAGS_} -O3 -march=x86-64 -mtune=intel -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -m64 -fPIC"
      LDFLAGS=""
      ASFLAGS="-D__ANDROID__"
    ;;
  esac

  TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=${BASEDIR}/android-toolchain
  NDK_SYSROOT=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/sysroot

  if [[ -e ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX} ]]; then
      rm -rf ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}
  fi

  [[ -d ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX} ]] || python3 ${NDK}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
     --arch ${NDK_ARCH} \
     --api ${ANDROID_API} \
     --stl libc++ \
     --install-dir=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}

  PREFIX=../../android/${ABI}


  export PATH=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/bin:$PATH
  export CROSS_PREFIX=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/bin/${NDK_ABIARCH}-
  export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
  export CPPFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
  export CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -std=c++11"
  export ASFLAGS="${ASFLAGS}"
  export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L${NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/lib"

  export AR="${CROSS_PREFIX}ar"
  export AS="${CROSS_PREFIX}clang"
  export CC="${CROSS_PREFIX}clang"
  export CXX="${CROSS_PREFIX}clang++"
  export LD="${CROSS_PREFIX}ld"
  export STRIP="${CROSS_PREFIX}strip"
  export RANLIB="${CROSS_PREFIX}ranlib"
  export CPP="${CROSS_PREFIX}cpp"
  export NM="${CROSS_PREFIX}nm"

  echo "**********************************************"
  echo "### Use NDK=${NDK}"
  echo "### Use ANDROID_API=${ANDROID_API}"
  echo "### Install directory: PREFIX=${PREFIX}"
  echo "**********************************************"
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm working on an Android app that requires custom video encoding using FFmpeg. I've tried to build a newer version of FFmpeg but couldn't integrate it into my project due to the older version requirement. I've also tried pre-built scripts that support a wide range of codecs, but they don't generate the necessary .a files for libraries like x264, VPX, and AAC.
